# Checklist Clone

Tags: azure-devops, clone, checklistbox, user-story

We started using Azure devops in the team and it has been very helpful with user story and checklist.
So my question is: Is it possible to make a user story with different checklist and then make a clone with the same checklist for the next userstory.

The checklist is different within every 20 user story so a general change of checklist cant be used.

I have tried making a template but it dosent capture the checklist value

Comment: What do you mean by "checklist"? Do you mean the list of tasks associated with the user story?

Comment: Hello Daniel
Yes the checklist that is associated with the user story.
Its an external checklist where it is mandatory to go through the different assignments.

Comment: You're using your own terminology to describe a feature of Azure DevOps, but I don't know what feature you're describing. Perhaps updating your question with a screenshot would be useful.